# git unable to merge unrelated histories shallow clone

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have shallow cloned a repo with depth 1 and create a local dev branch for development. After raising the PR, I have received merge conflicts, So I have pulled the latest master and tried to merge it with the dev branch.

Approach 1:

1. When I try to pull the branch, it says `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`
2. So, I deleted the local master and used switch to create a new branch `git switch -c master origin/master`
3. Now when I try to merge the master branch to local to resolve merge conflicts I am getting the error `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Approach 2:

1. Same till step 2 in Approach 1.
2. I have tried to cherry pick the commit that caused my merge conflicts. Since the repo is shallow cloned it does not have the commit history and throws error `bad object`.

I have tried `–allow-unrelated-histories`, there were so many merge conflicts that had to be hand fixed.

How to resolve this issue and merge master to my dev branch?

Comment: Try to unhallow your branch `git fetch --unshallow origin my/branch` or `--deepen` until you see a common commit between your branch and `master`

Comment: What command did you use to "pull master" ? Did you also use `--depth=1` ?

Comment: @LeGEC: it may not matter what got used for pull, depending on where the shallow graft occurs. I'd bet that this was the case here.

Comment: While cloning I have used `--depth=1`. When pulling I am unable to do pull directly on master it is throwing the same error `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. So, I used git switch to get the latest master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never<sup>1</sup> use `--allow-unrelated-histories`.  Instead, deepen (or "unshallow") your clone.  Edit: as per comments, you also need to convert your clone to a full clone (it's currently a single-branch clone, which I should have anticipated since using `--depth` during cloning defaults to creating a single-branch clone as well).

Merging, in Git, depends on *three* commits, not two:

- there is your *current commit* (aka `HEAD`), which will represent work done since some common starting point;
- there is some *other* commit, which will represent work done in some other branch since the *same common starting point;* and
- **there is a third commit, the *merge base*, which is this common starting point**.

When you run `git merge`, the argument you supply—generally a branch name like `feature` or `master`—locates the middle of these three: the "other" or `--theirs` commit.  The current or `--ours` commit is implied by what you have checked out.  The *third* commit, the common starting point, Git finds on its own.  But Git *needs the history* to find this commit.

History, in a Git repository, is nothing more or less than the *commits* in the repository.  A normal, non-shallow clone has *all the commits*,<sup>2</sup> so it has all the history.  The point of a *shallow* clone is to deliberately omit some history in the name of [expediency](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expediency).  For some purposes, this is fine (and hence actually expedient).  For *merging* it's *not* fine; don't do it.

If you have an existing shallow clone, e.g., because your CI system made one, consider running:

```
git remote set-branches origin "*"
git fetch --unshallow
```

The first command converts the clone to a standard full clone (undoing the single-branch-ness).  Note that you may be able to type in the `*` without quotes, but using the quotes like this should always work.

The second command redirects the usual `git fetch` operation such that it *removes the shallowness*.  If this proves to use too much in the way of system resources, you can alternatively use `git fetch --depth` or `git fetch --deepen` to incrementally *add more commits* to the shallow repository until you have enough history—enough commits—for `git merge` to locate the common starting point.  The problem with this approach is that there's no guarantee how deep that depth might be, which means there's no correct way to choose the *right* depth.  This in turn implies a loop, where you deepen the depth repeatedly until it's "enough", and *that* uses more and more system resources each time, which is presumably what you were trying to avoid in the first place through shallow cloning.

Most CI systems that do make shallow clones offer you a way to force a full clone in the first place (which is overall more efficient than making a shallow clone and then un-shallowing it).  So if the shallow clone is the problem, as in this case, just don't do it in the first place.

---

<sup>1</sup>Rule for advanced Git users: Never use `--allow-unrelated-histories` until you've proven somehow that it's OK.

<sup>2</sup>Remember, the core of a `git clone` operation is *copy all the commits, but none of the branch names*.  Git doesn't *need* branch names to function, but it does need commits.  We—humans—don't like using Git without branch names, so we always have Git create some, although CI systems sometimes don't bother with them; we use branch names and/or remote-tracking names (which remember some other repository's branch names) to find the interesting commits.  Git can use these as well, but *can* use the raw hash IDs directly, which is how those CI systems work.

Comment: I have done `git fetch --unshallow` on local master then I tried to git merge master on my dev branch. It threw the same error `refusing to merge unrelated histories`. Cherry picking the commit has not worked it said `fatal: bad object HashID`. I have double checked the hash ID and have done this on my dev branch `git cherry-pick hashID`

Comment: Do you perhaps also have a *single-branch* clone? What's the output of `git config --get remote.origin.fetch`?

Comment: It gave the output like this `+refs/heads/u/myname/AnotherDevBranch:refs/remotes/origin/u/myname/AnotherDevBranch` .This AnotherDevBranch is my branch not sure why it is set to AnotherDevBranch.

Comment: should this be pointing to master like this? +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/master?

Comment: Aha, that's the remaining problem then: yes, you have a single-branch clone. Run `git remote set-branches origin "*"` to convert to a full clone, then run `git fetch` to pick up the commits and create the appropriate remote-tracking names.